# Combining two line plots from different two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have two line graphs showing: one showing the decline of six species over the four sampling and the other showing the total decline of the same six species. I want to create a plot that has the six species shown individually and the total decline.

Below is an example of my data frame for the six species

```
 Week       Species      Unit
   1           A           13
   1           B           24
   2           B           15
   2           C           32
   3           C           43
   4           D           32
```

Below is the code I have used to create the line graph showing the decline of the six species

```
Species_Change<-ggplot(Total_Count, aes(x=Week, y=Unit, group=Scientific.name, color=Scientific.name)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow", "orange 2", "purple", "maroon 2", "blue", "purple 4","green"))+
  ylab("Total number of floral units over the four habitats")+
  xlab("Sampling round")+
  labs(col="Plant species")
```

Below is a sample of the data frame showing the total count of all species over the sampling period

```
Week           Unit
 1              32
 2              55
 3              73
 4              62
```

Below shows the code used to create the second line graph showing the total count of all species over the sampling rounds

```
Total_Change<-ggplot(Total_Round, aes(x=Week, y=Unit, )) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Total number of floral units over the four habitats")+
  xlab("Sampling round")+
  labs(col="Plant species")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can add a new species called "total" to your `Total_count` `data.frame`. Using the data you provided:

Data

```
dput(Total_Count)
structure(list(Week = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Unit = c(13L, 24L, 15L, 32L, 43L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
dput(Total_Round)
structure(list(Week = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Unit = c(32, 55, 73, 62)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Code

```
Total_Round$Species <- factor(rep("Total",nrow(Total_Round))) # Create total species
df <- rbind(Total_Count, Total_Round) # Merge both data.frames
AllwithTotal_Species_Change<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Week, y=Unit, group=Species, color=Species)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow", "orange 2", 
                                 "purple", "maroon 2", 
                                 "blue", "purple 4",
                                 "green"))+
  ylab("Total number of floral units over the four habitats")+
  xlab("Sampling round")+
  labs(col="Plant species")
AllwithTotal_Species_Change
```

[image: plotresult]

Hope this helps!